# BibTeX equivalent for "inproceedings" in Schema.org

Tags: schema.org, bibtex

I'm listing my conference publications on [my homepage](http://schrieveslaach.de/publications.html) (German website). I want to annotate those publications with Schema.org. In `bibtex` those publications are `inproceedings` ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX#Entry_types)).

Schema.org provides [`CreativeWork`](https://schema.org/CreativeWork) and subclasses. But, I can not find any type suitable for a conference publication. I'm not sure if [`Article`](https://schema.org/Article) is the right class to choose.

Do you have any recommendation to annotate a conference publication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`CreativeWork`](http://schema.org/CreativeWork) is definitely the correct parent type, and if there should be no suitable sub-type, you could simply go with `CreativeWork`.

But I think the sub-type [`Article`](http://schema.org/Article) is suitable, and in your case probably its sub-type **[`ScholarlyArticle`](http://schema.org/ScholarlyArticle)**.

Note that there is also the [Bibliographic Extension](http://bib.schema.org/) of Schema.org, but as far as scientific publications are concerned, it currently only seems to define a [`Thesis`](http://bib.schema.org/Thesis) type, which doesn’t help in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I think none of the classes really matches to scientific publications. I will stick with `Article`.